# Base tag not working correctly

Tags: html, hyperlink, radix

I have this code here at the top of all my pages:

```
<base href="http://example.com/dev/">
```

and in this page (http://example.com/dev/index.php/foo/bar/) I have this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/common.css" />
```

However my browser keeps trying to load:

> http://example.com/dev/index.php/foo/style/common.css

when it should be:

> http://example.com/dev/style/common.css

**UPDATE **

```
<html>
<head>
        <base href="http://example.com/dev/" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style/video.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style/common.css" />
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Peter

Comment: `style/` is a relative URL.  Try using `/style/common.css` instead

Comment: `<base>` has to be before anything with a `href` attribute. Make sure the `<base>` is first.

Comment: @briansol relative URLs work with the base element.

Comment: The base url as at the very top of the head section

Comment: When I add the / at the front of the href source it loads example.com/style/common.css

Comment: Try `<base href="http://example.com/dev/index.html">` or index.php. I'm thinking it might have something to do with your .htaccess file or some kind of apache rewrite thing.

Comment: The code posted originally is correct as such. The UPDATA section confuses this, since the URLs are different and as you say in a comment, these work as defined. So the problem is in some code that was not disclosed. Please post a complete HTML document that reproduces the error and specify the browser(s) tested.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had a similar problem.  The problem occurred when the page was fed through a cgi.  This did not work for me:

```
<base href="http://example.com/dev/">
```

but, the following does:

```
<base href="/dev/">
```

Comment: For some reason, the trailing slash is VERY important. Thanks a lot.